# Grammar: French conditionnel in English?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, conditionals, conditional-perfect

Could anybody help me here, please? I’d like to know the grammatical form of the verb “can" in the following examples:

> 18y old Tim is asked by a relative what he’s going to do with his
>   life. After some hesitation, he finally answers: “Well, I COULD help
>   my father on the farm - but I’m not sure if I want to be a farmer. I
>   COULD also go to university but I don’t like studying… or I COULD
>   train really hard and become a football pro. I don’t now yet, too many
>   options…” Ten years later, Tim is lying on the street, an empty wine
>   bottle in his hand, and he’s saying: “What ever happened to me,… I
>   COULD HAVE become a football pro, if only I had tried harder,... or I
>   COULD HAVE helped my father - but now he’s sold the farm.”

It's like conditionnel 1 and conditionnel 2 in French ("je pourrais / j’aurais pû”), but how is it called in English?

Thank you!

Comment: *Could* is the past tense of *can*.

Comment: Not very different from the usage as in the **first word of the first sentence** of the question. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: It's no always the past tense of can @tchrist. It can also refer to *possibility*, *suggestion*, etc. depending on the context, which is more of the case in the first few places. He's not talking about his past, but the future, about what he*'s going to do* with his life.

Comment: @Neeku It’s still a past-tense inflection. That doesn’t mean it isn’t used for other things as well.

Comment: *I could have helped* is indeed a past-tense conditional.

Comment: So what you want is the *names* for the various uses of *could*? I don't think there's a standard set that would be understood by most educated people (like *conditionnel 1* and *conditionnel 2* in French).

Comment: Of course it is very interesting to discuss the exact nature of _could_, whether it is a defective verb or simply a past tense of can mapped to a conditional aspect, but I think that the OP may be helped more with a [link to conditionals](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/secondconditional/menu.php) as an answer to the question what the English equivalent of French _conditionnel_ is...

Comment: Maybe [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb#English) could help. It seems to say that this is the *epistemic sense* of the modal verb *could*. Although, as I said above, the terms *epistemic* and *deontic* would only be understood by linguists and grammarians. The rest of us just use the grammar without knowing the name for it.

Comment: We don’t know what you’re actually asking here. Per Wikipedia, [“Le conditionnel en français comporte trois temps, dont les formes sont tirées de temps d'autres modes: un temps du présent (**conditionnel présent**, ex: *je mangerais*) et deux temps du passé, considérés comme équivalents en nuance (**conditionnel passé 1ʳᵉ forme**, ex:  *j’aurais mangé*; **conditionnel passé 2ᵉ forme**, ex: *j'eusse mangé”*.](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel)

Answer (score 2):

"Could" is a modal verb in English that has various meanings in various sentences. This is more of a grammar for usages of modal verbs that you could have found by searching, but anyhow, I always find subscription-only LDOCE pretty helpful, so I'm quoting its definitions here:

> 1. **Past ability**: used as the past tense of 'can' to say what someone was able to do or was allowed to do in the past:
>      *The
>      teacher said we could all go home.*
>      *I couldn't get tickets after
>      all, they were sold out.*
> 2. **Possibility**:
>
>    *a.* used to say that something is possible or might happen:
>     
>      *Most accidents in the home could be prevented.*
>
>    *b.* used to say that something was a possibility in the past, but
>      did not actually happen:
>      *I could have warned you if I had known
>      where you were.*
> 3. **Emphasizing your feelings (spoken)**: used to emphasize how happy, angry, etc. you are by saying how you want to express your
>      feelings:
>      *I was so angry that I could have killed her.*
> 4. **Requesting (spoken)**: used to make a polite request:
>      *Could I have a glass of water, please?*
> 5. **Suggesting**: used to suggest doing something:
>      *You could ask your doctor for a check-up.*
> 6. **Annoyance (spoken)**: used to show that you are annoyed about someone's behavior:
>      *You could have told me you were going to be
>      late (=you should have told me, but you did not)!*
> 7. ...
> 8. ...
> 9. ...

The last three aren't all that much related to your sentences, so I'm not putting them here, and you can always search and find out more about them as your homework!

In the quotation you've provided, the first three imply the possibility (2.a.) and the three others can fit in 2.b., 3, or 6, however if you search and read some grammar books, you'll find out more about *could have* or *if clauses* (4th *could* in your quotation).

Comment: *Could* is ever and always a **past-tense inflection** of *can*.  English uses past and non-past inflections for a very, **very** wide variety of times and aspects; they certainly do not simply correspond to past-versus-present or anything trivial like that.  Inflectionally, it is a past-tense form.  Notionally, this can vary. Just as present tense can be used for the future, so too can pas
t tense.

Comment: Do you mean you disagree with what the dictionary says? I haven't made up my answer, but referenced it clearly. @tchrist People are taking their time to type and post answers here, and it's not right to down-vote whatever you don't agree with.

Comment: I don’t disagree with what the OED says, no: **“could** /kʊd/, *pa. t.* (and *obs.* and *dial. pa. pple.*) of **can** *v.* q.v.”  And I will certainly downvote answers that are wrong.

Comment: @tchrist So you disagree with what LDOCE says, to be more precise? Plus all the grammar books out there. (:

Comment: You are completely and utterly missing the point here.  I’m not going to cite the entire OED entry for ***can*** here, not even a smidgen.  It is extremely long, exceeded only by that of ***will***.  I cannot recommend that you read them strongly enough.  You appear not to understand tense inflections in English and the complex mapping to aspect they enjoy, particularly as modals are applied, and this is too small a space for me to explain all this to you.

Comment: @tchrist Answer is edited. Do you still disagree with it?

Comment: @tchrist There are quite a few scholars (I believe John Lawler is one of them) who consider _can_ and _could_ (as well as _will_ and _would_, _shall_ and _should_, _may_ and _might_) to be separate modals in Modern English, rather than simple inflection—leaving the entire modal class as completely uninflectable, defective verbs with only one form per verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Be that as it may, given the question of how the French call grammatical forms like *pourrais* the *conditionnel*, so what do we call the grammatical form  of the word *could* in English, there is not going to be any more satisfying answer than *modal*. And even that runs the risk that the OP will now go away thinking that *modal* in English means *conditionnel* in French — which it certainly doesn’t.

Comment: The LDOCE breakdown looks accurate and useful to me. Deciding and explaining what words are actually used to mean / facilitate in sentences is more important than deciding on whether to lump or split. That _is_ important, but the fact that grammarians disagree on classification shows that it is often arrogant to claim one classification system as 'the' classification system.